# Custom bottom panel with overlay mode in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, overlay, android-gridview

I have a gridview filling up entire screen and a panel at the bottom of the screen. The panel is slightly transparent, so I can see grid view items scrolling below it. The problem is that when I reach the end of scroll, I cannot pull the last items of grid view above this panel. What is the general approach to it? I'm tinkering with adding fake gridview elements so that it makes the last "real ones" slide from beneath this panel, but I guess it's not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Actually, I think your fake gridview elements solution might be the cleanest, from a UI perspective.

Comment: Hmm,  I thought that there might be some common way of dealing with such situations.  What if I had another type of view instead of grid view? Is there a way to detect end of scroll and reposition the view?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem there would be smoothly transitioning from scrolling the View to "dragging" it, and vice versa. I'm playing around with it. I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. If to you figure it out I'll be glad to see your results.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MikeM. Have you managed to figure something out?

Comment: Nothing acceptable. Resizing works most fluidly, but it pulls the bottom of the View up over the bottom row, and trying to make it scroll back causes ugly stuttering. I'll have some free time later to play with it, but your original solution just might be the best one.

Comment: Hmm ok,  apparently it is really best resolved with those fake views. Anyway,  thanks for your help!